# Why I get 500 internal server error when debugging site after saving view page and refresh browser?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, .net-core

While debugging a site that work correctly  made with .net core, if I save one view page in visual studio (example index.cshtml), at the refresh of the browser there is a 500 - Internal server error.
Also if I save page without any change in javascript, css, html or Razor i must re-start debug instead to simply refresh browser like i done until two days agò.
The site work fine until I save "view" page and refresh browser.

I think is impossible that there is a bug in the code, because this project work fine, until now I usually edited html or css while debug running for save time and I hope to solve problem to continue to do it.

I try to run command:
PM> dotnet restore
I found it in a stackoverflow post but it not solve error.

Error page is about 10K rows, the initial part of the error in browser is:

TITLE: Internal server errror

PAGE:
An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Generated Code

The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
+
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index), @"mvc.1.0.view", @"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml")]
The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

Comment: Have you tried running a Clean and Rebuild? The fact that `Attribute` cannot be found in `System.Private.CoreLib` tells me that the restore or build action may not have completed correctly. Doing a clean then rebuild should force Visual Studio to re-acquire the correct version of `System.Private.CoreLib`